# Mac shortcuts for Finder and Safari

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks

I am having trouble adjusting to a Mac after years of using a PC. When I open finder by pressing command + option + spacebar, how do I cycle through the options on the left using only my keyboard?

I don't think you can actually do the above, but I asked anyway. More importantly, when I open the bookmarks tabs in Safari by pressing command + shift + L, how do I cycle through my bookmarks and move over to my reading list by only using shortcuts on my keyboard? When you are trying to toggle back and forth between Safari address bar and the webpage, how does one do this? It's annoying because sometimes when I hit spacebar, I want to be jumping down the page one page at a time, but if I'm stuck in address bar after hitting command + L, I don't know how to get back to the webpage without using the mouse. How do I do this?

I generally just want to use my mouse as little as possible for speed.

I use a macbook pro on OS 10.9

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that it's possible. I've already searched it and went on [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343).

EDIT : You may be able to create your own keyboard shortcuts in every apps. For example you can create a shortcut that opens your reading list in safari. Furthermore you may want to activate tab for all controls in System Settings, Keyboard, Shortcuts and check the box at the end of the window. Without this checked, tab will only switch between text boxes and lists.

See [this page](http://www.chriswrites.com/10-ways-to-navigate-mac-os-x-using-just-keyboard-and-gestures/) for more information. It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer one part.  If you're in Safari's address bar, you can hit Tab and jump to the main page.  If the page has some type of input box, the cursor might actually jump into the input box, which doesn't really help.  But if there is no input, the page will get the focus, and you can use Space to jump down the page.